# What's the easiest way to generate post slugs for posts migrated from a custom blog setup?

Tags: wordpress

I've had a blog since 2003. A few years ago, I moved it from a custom blogging system that I wrote myself to learn PHP to Wordpress. I wrote a custom script to do the import and all fields imported fine (title, date created/edited, post body, meta, replies, etc) EXCEPT the post-slug column. At the time, I either didn't think about the slugs or didn't think I'd ever need them, so the script didn't generate a nice, sanitized slug from the title.

Fast forward until a few weeks ago when I decided to setup pretty permalinks (for SEO and human-readability) that use this format:

```
http://siteurl.com/idOfPost/sanitized-name-of-title
```

All the posts I've created in Wordpress since the import have the sanitized title at the end, but all the posts I imported do not have the title at the end (since the post-slug field is empty for those posts). The pages come up fine with just the id, but I'd like them to have the title. I can't run the custom script again without a lot of modifications because the Wordpress tables have changed somewhat.

Does anyone know of a Wordpress-friendly script or plugin that will generate the slugs for me? I could probably write one myself, however, I'd rather use a tested solution that's stood the test of time (or at least the test of a bunch of Wordpress users who use it).

I've Googled and haven't come across a solution that seems robust/safe enough to suit me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing [my own plugin](http://www.jerrytravis.com/598/wordpress-plugin-to-generate-post-slugs) that generates slugs for posts that don't have them.

Even though this is an apparently obscure problem, maybe this small plugin will be useful to someone besides me.

Comment: Thanks for this! Worked well for a custom blog that I just migrated to WP (10 years worth of posts) Cheers!